# Can a node I am connected to with monerod cause any damage to me if it is malicious?

Tags: monerod

I am not referring to a remote node who I have to trust to give me an accurate copy of the blockchain, but any one of the many nodes I connect to to synch my blockchain.

I am imagining a scenario where one of the nodes I have connected to is intent on inflicting maximum damage. What are his options or possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

This may be worth a read:

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/40383/what-is-the-protection-against-a-malicious-node-with-a-bad-block-chain

This would mean that a node cannot simply make a blockchain up as it is compared with peers so it must generate an equally as valid one so thus in order to perform a malicious attack with a bad blockchain must contain 51% of the hashing power.

Comment: A "bad" blockchain with 51% would still contain all valid TX-es so how could you tell it's bad unless it's repeatedly removing some TX-es or censoring some key images etc.; Your node is actually verifying that the "rules" have been followed since day 0 so even 51% won't trick it into accepting something violating those rules. 51% only let's you censor and reorder TX-es, but won't let you make invalid ones. That's why you want to run a node :) One way to cause problems would be to import some untrusted .raw file without verifying TX-es but that's another story. Node "rules" trump hashpower.